# Javascript font injection in head in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, head

I am trying to add google fonts to the page after loading.
I am using this line

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML + url;
```

where url looks like

```
"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=...";
```

Works very well in chrome, firefox, chrome on android, safari on iphone.

But when tested in IE, it makes the tab crash. With a bug report to Microsoft and everything. Tested on two different PCs, IE 8, IE 10, Win7 and Win8, with the same result.

Any alternative ?

Comment: Just curious why you would be doing this after load?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.appendChild`

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var content = document.createTextNode("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=...");
head.appendChild(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add simple to the head?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=....' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the font in the actual code then add this style via css:

```
<script>
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = 'elements-to-add-font-to{font-family: "font name";}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/PFF2A/